# limit no of filepaths using os.walk where huge files in a directory

Tags: python, queue, filepath, os.walk

I have an application. One method which will allow a directory path and returns list of file paths under given directory using os.walk

I would like to read certain no of files(some threshold value like bring 20 file paths) in a directory where has huge no files and stores in Queue. Here i can have a check of file path with its status in database.

Next time when i call the same method with same directory, it should return next set of file paths by excluding already returned file paths.

Scenario:
Lets assume, D:/Sample_folder has 1000 no of files.

my_dir = "D:/Sample_folder"

def read_files(directory):
    file_paths = []

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        file_paths.append(file_path)

return file_paths
```

read_files(my_dir) == which will give first 100 no of files in first turn
                    Next turn, it should give remaining set of 100 files 
                    like so...

Any ideas or sample scripts for this.

Comment: so you want a queue of lists, each with 100 filepaths?

Comment: Yes, each time i should get 100 different paths by excluding already returned paths.No Queues,I need a method should return a list of paths. Later those list items i will keep in Queue for other calculation.

Comment: Does your `my_dir` have subdirectories, or is it just a flat dir with say 1000 text files?

Comment: It can have sub directories as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have `files` populated, this should do.

```
import Queue

paths = Queue.Queue()

current_list = []

for i, path in enumerate(files):

    # Second case to make sure we dont add a blank list
    if i % 100 == 0 and i != 0:
        paths.put(current_list)
        current_list = []

    current_list.append(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Here is a possible solution using a class, but it doesn't add much code. The main idea is to pop off an element each time it gets accessed. So the workflow is to make a `FileListIter` object, then call `.next()` on it to return a list of the next `100` files to do something with and then the object forgets them. You can call `.has_next()` to check if you're out of files. If you pass an argument to next like `.next(2)`, then it will instead give back the first 2 files in a list.

CODE:

```
import os

class FileListIter(object):
    #Initialize the files
    def __init__(self,directory):
        file_paths = []
        for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                file_paths.append(file_path)

        self.files = file_paths

    #When called w/out args give back the first 100 files, otherwise the first n
    def next(self,n=100):
        ret,self.files = self.files[:n],self.files[n:]
        return ret

    #Check if there are any files left
    def has_next(self):
        return len(self.files) > 0

d = '/home/rob/stack_overflow'
files_gen = FileListIter(d) #<-- this makes an object

while files_gen.has_next():
    file_subset = files_gen.next(2)
    print file_subset
```